# Does Jenkins wait for the threads started by the current test to terminate in order to start another test?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, jenkins

i have a code that schedules and runs threads as `TimerTask`-s.

Jenkins controls the sequence of tests it runs-- doesn't run another until one test unit returns.

However - does Jenkins control the threads-started-from-within-test in a similar way?

Our tests are failing, and this the only reason i can think of.

On the other hand, one wouldn't be surprised an integration/build environment has the strict control-- launches one test, 
waits till the processor clears each&every thread it started, and goes on with the next test.

TIA

Comment: Do your tests run correctly when run outside Jenkins, e.g. in your IDE? Are these JUnit tests? JUnit tests terminate when the main thread terminates, I would imagine regardless of whether they are run by Jenkins or from command line. Do you have an example test you could share?

Comment: the code is a spread out to too many classes to orgnize a sample here. the tests are fine each-- the logic isn't any complex. they've been running fine on Eclipse. started getting the errors after i committed the code. all JUnit tests.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? This is not enough information. For example, just last week, I had my unit tests failing when run under hudson while everything worked in my IDE (Netbeans). It turned out the reason was hudson did a clean check out on every build, and a test that read all input files with test data from a directory executed the tests in a different order (oldest files first when run in netbeans, alphabetically first in hudson because checked out in that order). The real problem was not properly resetting state after each file. Easy fix, but difficult to track down.

Comment: @Axel - clean start would agree w/my test logic. it's the threads overlapping. but thanks for the further useful info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JUnit test cases terminate when the main thread terminates. If you schedule TimerTasks to be run, your test will not wait them to finish unless you make it to, which could be your problem. You can make the main thread wait for example with a latch:

```
public class TimerThreadTest {

  final static int NUM_THREADS = 5;
  final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(NUM_THREADS);

  @Test
  public void threadTest() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Starting");
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++){
      final int threadNo = i;
      TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            latch.countDown();
            System.out.println("thread " + threadNo + " done");
        }
      };
      timer.schedule(tt, 1000);
    }
    latch.await();
    System.out.println("Main thread done");
  }
}
```